# Are these multiple php-cgi processes normal to have?

Tags: ubuntu, lighttpd

I'm trying to understand why my server is so slow. I've run `ps -ef` and I found out this:

```
www-data 29185 29184  0 11:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi
www-data 29188 29185  0 11:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php-cgi
www-data 29189 29185  0 11:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php-cgi
www-data 29190 29185  0 11:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php-cgi
www-data 29191 29185  0 11:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php-cgi
www-data 29192 29184  0 11:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi
www-data 29194 29192  0 11:11 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/php-cgi
www-data 29195 29192  0 11:11 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php-cgi
www-data 29196 29192  0 11:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php-cgi
www-data 29197 29192  0 11:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

is normal I have 10 process php-chi on a server without traffic (for now) ?
Web Server: lighttpd
OS: ubuntu 10

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running PHP via FastCGI, sure. They stay resident so that they're ready to process PHP scripts on demand.